# Jumping forward within panels

Tags: c#, panel, visual-studio-2015

I have a total of 10 panels. They are all on top of each other. There is a location where I want to jump forward a few panels. For example, on panel 7 the user can click the "Skip" button and jump forward to panel 10 and continue OR they can continue from panel 7 to panel 8, panel 9, and then arrive at panel 10.

I've discovered that the "Skip" button isn't going directly to panel 10, although I have placed the code `panel10.Visible = true;`. Instead it is making panel 10 visible after panel 9 has been arrived at. Hence, the user must go through all the panels to see panel 10 instead of clicking and it jumping there directly (not seeing any panels in between). I've set all the panels visibility to false.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Have panel 10 display after clicking "Skip" on panel 7?

Comment: Are these panels parent control are the same? Is the location of each panel also same? Additional code would be of help. As a suggestion you can manipulate the `Panel.Position` instead of the `Visible` property, if all are overlapping and on the same position. Hence swapping each panel base on your current page index.

Comment: If everything would be set up as you say it would work. At least it sounds like it although not seeing the code makes it hard to actually know. You can write a test routine and write out all panels' parent to make sure none is nested. It is hard to keep 10 panels right in the designer or are they generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If I want to skip forward some panels, I have to set the panels in between visibility to true. Hence my answer is:

```
panel8.Visibility = true;
panel9.Visibility = true;
panel10.Visibility = true;
```

Now I arrive at panel 10 from panel 7 with one click.